# Delegate not finding parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delegation

I have this class

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :order
  delegate :foo, to: :order
```

And when I run method foo, I get this error:

```
Email#foo delegated to order.foo, but order is nil
```

However, when I add this method to Email, suddenly it works

```
def order
  Order.find( order_id )
end
```

Why would this happen? I'm happy that it's working now, but I'm confused as to why it's failing. I'm working in a code base that's new-ish to me, and have not used delegation in my own projects before.

Thanks

Comment: I certainly can't see what the problem would be, and I'll be curious to know what you find out. Your work-around is not great since you'll now run a new query and get a new instance of Order every time #order is called.

Comment: Are you sure that your Email object you are testing has an associated Order? You could add a `validates :order_id, presence: true` to force the relation